# How to put public comment blog using facebook in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I am a new in a iphone application development i have a required to publish a wall using a facebook connectivity so that user can write a comment on that wall so how to provide this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at facebook's API: [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com)

Not really sure what you are looking for and what framework you're using but you might be interested in looking at this http://pointlesscrap.net/mkabefook/